# How can we Rasterize only 3dplots profile without box, axes or labels?

Tags: plotting, formatting

I would like to export a 3dplot where box, axes, and labels are in a vector format, but the 3d plot profile can be an image, similar to [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/33vstk45qsukx4j/example.pdf?dl=0).

```
lebl = MaTeX["\\color{red}\\text{Lable}", FontSize -> 16];
axeslebl = 
  MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 16] & /@ {"\\color{blue}x-axis", 
    "\\color{blue}y-axis", "\\color{blue}z-axix"};

plot3d = 
 Plot3D[5 Sin[x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Green, FontSize -> 15}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[lebl, Scaled[{.6, 1.1}]], 
    Rotate[Text[axeslebl[[1]], Scaled[{.29, 0}]], -\[Pi]/8], 
    Rotate[Text[axeslebl[[2]], Scaled[{.09, 0.99}]], \[Pi]/4.5], 
    Rotate[Text[axeslebl[[3]], Scaled[{-0.1, 0.5}]], \[Pi]/1.8]}, 
  ImagePadding -> 40, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 280, 
  ClippingStyle -> None, AxesStyle -> Black, BoxStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Exporting this as a pdf `Export[".pdf", plot3d]` doesn't give a vector format of the box, axes, and labels. I remember that in MMA10 it was working.

Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: MMA does not provide vector format for 3D graphics  in pdf after versin 10.

Comment: An old thread: "[Rasters in 3D graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6301676/590388)."